# How Set DateTimeField in django with postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i had in model DateTimeField and in postgres display `2017-08-18 00:00:00` i want to change it  to `2017-08-18`

**models.py**

```
class sortiestk(models.Model):
idsort=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
qtesrt = models.IntegerField(default=0)
datesrt=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,blank=True)
ref=models.ForeignKey(Produit)
codmag=models.ForeignKey(magasin)
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def srti(request):
if request.method == 'POST' :
    received_json_data=json.loads(request.body)
    refpr = received_json_data["srtfprod"]
    prod = Produit.objects.get(ref=refpr)
    qtepro = prod.qte
    qtesrt = int(received_json_data["qte"])
    if qtepro < qtesrt :
        return JsonResponse ({'boo':True})
    else :
        m = magasin.objects.get(codmag=received_json_data["refmag"])
        s = sortiestk(
        qtesrt=qtesrt, 
        datesrt = received_json_data["dat"],
        ref = prod ,
        codmag = m )
        p = Produit.objects.get(ref=refpr)
        p.qte = p.qte - qtesrt
        p.save()
        s.save()
        return redirect ('/ges/sortie/')
```

when i display in template i get `Sept. 19, 2017, midnight` i just want display date not date with timezone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `date()` method:

```
datetime.datetime.now().date()

datesrt=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now().date(),blank=True)
```